# How to identify unique people in a MySQL table using more than one criteria

Tags: mysql, select, unique

I have a ~200k record table `dat` of people with their identifying data as well as a test date and result, here's a dummy version:

```
+----+---------+----------+------------+----------+------------+--------+
| id | surname | forename | dob        | SchoolID | testDate   | result |
+----+---------+----------+------------+----------+------------+--------+
|  1 | Smith   | Mary     | 1980-04-11 | NULL     | 2005-10-12 |  14.32 |
|  2 | Smith   | Mary     | 1980-04-11 | 1234     | 2007-03-02 |   18.1 |
|  3 | Jones   | Kim      | 1978-10-24 | 4657     | 2002-04-14 |  24.31 |
|  4 | Jones   | Kim      | NULL       | 4567     | 2002-10-08 |  19.02 |
|  5 | Roberts | Kim      | 1978-10-24 | 4567     | 2003-12-18 |  14.19 |
|  6 | Roberts | Kim      | 1978-10-24 | 4567     | 2005-02-11 |  18.26 |
+----+---------+----------+------------+----------+------------+--------+
```

I would like to identify people who have had more than one test, and create a new column `uniqueID` that gives unique people a new id. Sadly, my database is not very tidy so I need to use several criteria to separate these records into unique individuals:

- surname, forename and dob are the same (since SchoolID is often missing or wrong)
- surname, forename and SchoolID are the same (since D.O.B. is sometimes not entered, or 
  entered wrong)
- forename, dob and SchoolID are the same (people sometimes get married)
- etc.

In the example above, there are just two unique people in the table Mary Smith and Kim Roberts nee Jones, so this `uniqueID` column should end up being:

```
+----+----------+
| id | uniqueID |
+----+----------+
|  1 |        1 |
|  2 |        1 |
|  3 |        2 |
|  4 |        2 |
|  5 |        2 |
|  6 |        2 |
+----+----------+
```

Although I've been dabbled a bit with MySQL for a few years I'm still a beginner. I've been searching and trying things for a few days, and so far I have managed this:

```
SELECT surname, forename, SchoolID 
   FROM dat 
   GROUP BY CONCAT(surname, forename, SchoolID);
```

which is the second criterion, for example, (that I was planning to give an auto incrementing key to in a new table, then join back in as the unique ID), but I'm not getting very with these multiple criteria, so any help much appreciated!

Thanks
Nick

Comment: Did you guys ever think about adding SS# to the table to easily identify people?

Comment: That is supposed to be what SchoolID is for. Sadly in real life it didn't work out as was frequently not entered, people were reissued new ones (and even the same numbers were issued more than once).

Comment: If somebody got married and has a new surname how are you suppose to match that person?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried "SELECT distinct"?

Comment: Yes - but never successfully so far to tie in all these different criteria. It seemed to do roughly the same as GROUP BY, i.e. was fine for one constraint but I haven't managed to get it to do all.

Comment: Hmm, how about you search with DOB rather than schoolID since there are more than one "Kims"? I think it's more likely that there is a unique name, last name, and dob rather than name, last name, and school id.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through self joins. I'd do it in multiple steps, though - from best to weakest match.

So, assuming schoolID is reliable when present, this is how you find the duplicates:

```
select *
from   dat parent, 
       dat child
where  parent.id      <> child.id
and    parent.schoolid =  child.schoolid
```

(Apologies for antediluvian join syntax).

Run that, and see if you get any oddities; if you like it, turn it into an update. Updates with a self join are a little painful in MySQL, and the simplest way is to create a view to join.

```
create view dupes as

select   min(parent.id) as uniqueid, child.id
from     dat parent, 
         dat child
where    parent.schoolid =  child.schoolid
group by child.id

update  ignore dat, dupes
set     dat.uniqueid =   dupes.uniqueid
where    dat.id      = dupes.id
```

Now, you go to the second strongest link, something like:

```
    select *
    from   dat parent, 
           dat child
    where  parent.id      <> child.id
    and    parent.uniqueID is  null
    and    child.uniqueID  is  null
    and    parent.forename = child.forename
    and    parent.surname  = child.surname
    and    parent.dob      = child.dob
```

Again, run it, check the data for oddities, turn into an update statement.

Next, relax the restrictions - it's okay if we have previously matched the parent to another record, so we can remove the check for null:

```
select *
from   dat parent, 
       dat child
where  parent.id      <> child.id
and    child.uniqueID  is  null
and    parent.forename = child.forename
and    parent.surname  = child.surname
and    parent.dob      = child.dob
```

And so on, and so forth. 
By working from strongest likelihood down, you reduce the risk of a fairly tenuous similarity overriding a clear link (e.g. two people called "Kim" who happened to be born on 1978-10-24,

By running selects first, and turning them into updates second, you avoid human error.

Comment: Your first block of code runs and produces the duplicates - however the second block, the update part, isn't working for me - I removed the presumably erroneous extra period yet it returns an error related to the 'from' part... Many thanks,

Comment: You're right - the update doesn't work in MySQL. Working on a way to deal with that...

Comment: Great - thanks. The new code is now working, and I've learnt loads from just typing it out! So far, I've got unique IDs for the three different school IDs, however, the second SELECT is producing an empty set, because of the constraints that uniqueIDs are NULL (there is only one). Taking these constraints out doesn't seem to be working for me but am going to persevere! Thanks again!